# SQL works with phpmyadmin on server but not in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have XAMPP v3.2.2 installed on my Windows 7 machine as a part of maintaining my Wordpress web site. Using phpmyadmin I can run SELECT statements fine. However, I just tried to run the following statement:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`,'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/old.jpg','https://www.jimplaxco.com/blog/new.jpg') WHERE `ID` ='5';
```

Pasting the code into the phpmyadmin SQL box for the wp_posts table results in a slew of syntax errors (see image below). Befuddled I pasted the code into two different online validators both of which gave the statement a clean bill of health. I then logged in to my web hosting account and pasting the code into the SQL box in the phpmyadmin there and the code worked just fine.

Any insights into why my local install of phpmyadmin is flagging as invalid an apparently good statement would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: phpmyadmin error messages]

Comment: That's a PHP error not a SQL error.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in an old version of phpMyAdmin - https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12020

Comment: XAMPP v3.2.2 sounds very old.

Comment: @BartFriederichs this bug was fixed in 2016 :)

Comment: Thank you. I will update XAMPP and let you know what happens.

Comment: Off topic: general MySQL rule when the data type of a column `ID ='5'` is a INT query it as a INT don't **never** use quotes.. MySQL auto casting can mess things up and can render indexes useless.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to the comments on my original question, I exported my Wordpress database, uninstalled XAMPP, installed XAMPP 7.3.0, and imported my Wordpress db.

In phpmyadmin, pasting in the SQL UPDATE statement from my original post resulted in no syntax errors and the statement ran correctly.

So the problem was not with the SQL statement itself but with something in my old installation of XAMPP.

Thanks to the commenters for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: OOPS. Except that after clearing my browser cache I can no longer log into Wordpress. Looks like the old version of Wordpress that I am using (old because of a no-longer-compatible-with-Wordpress plugin) is not compatible with the new version of PHP that comes with XAMPP.